# Описание процесса поиска имени

Tags: c++

Помогите описать процесс поиска имени х в последней строке фрагмента:

```
struct S { static int x; void f(); };
int S::x;
int x;
void S::f() { x; // <-- }
```

Comment: Поле класса имеет более высокий приоритет и (молча) перекрывает глобальную переменную `x`. @vegorov В приведенном примере нет локальных переменных.

Comment: @VTT ну да, с терминологией у меня не очень =) локальной переменной я обозвал статичное поле класса. Локальная переменная перебила бы статичное поле, верно ? `void S::f() { int x = 2; std::cout << x << this->x << ::x << std::endl; }`

Comment: @vegorov Это да.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неквалифицированное имя `x` в данном случае использовано в определении члена класса, располагающемся за пределами определения самого класса. При этом имя использовано *после* идентификатора определяемого члена класса (`S::f` в данном случае). В такой ситуации процесс поиска неквалифицированных имен описывается [6.4.1/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.unqual#8):

1. Делается поиск вверх в том блоке, в котором использовано имя и далее в содержащих его блоках. (В данном случае ничего не находится)
2. Делается поиск члена данного класса или члена его базового класса в соответствии с правилами [10.7](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.member.lookup). (Вот тут-то и находится член класса `S::x`)

Имя найдено, поиск закончен.

P.S. В 6.4.1/8 по ссылке приводится аналогичный, но более "навороченный" пример поиска неквалифицированного имени `i` с заходом в большее количество разнообразных областей видимости.